# Three.js - Change scene background on event

Tags: javascript, three.js

**Hi** devs! I'm asking for help. I need to change scene background on event.
I set background with `scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);`
When i try to change it on event, nothing happend.
How can i do this?

Comment: Show us more of your code - how do you attach your handler and what does it do. Also, what version of THREE are you using (``scene.background = ...`` is available since ``r78``).

Comment: Hello, thanx for attention.
`var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xff0000);

webgl render  my scene with simple perspective camera in loop`

somewhere in code:
`$('button').click(function () {
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
})`

Shortly its look like this.
R81dev

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i found the problem.